# Creating Global Dataframe for Spark Streaming job

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark streaming job that continuously receiving messages from kafka. The streaming job will:

1. Do filtering on the newly received message
2. Append the filtering left messages to the global dataframe.
3. When the global dataframe received 1000 rows of records, do a sum operation.

My question are:

1. How to create the global dataframe? is it just simply creating a dataframe outside, before the loop of

> directKafkaStream.foreachRDD { .... }

2. How to effectively handle the operation of global dataframe, the step 3 in this task. Do I have to embed the operation into the `foreachRDD` loop?

Comment: 1000 is a very small amount. Do you really need here a DataFrame?